# PHP login system from Wikibooks: to be trusted?

Tags: php, authentication, session

Have anyone reading the description of PHP user authentication system at Wikibooks?
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/User_login_systems

Is it good?  Secure?  Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are toons of way to do a user authentication system, so it really depends on what you need. This one looks OK for simple authentification.

However, please note the following code they wrote:

```
$db = new Database(); // Database abstraction class.
$email_address = $db->esc($_POST['email']);
$password = $db->esc($_POST['password']);
```

What is important in this code is the `Database abstraction class`. It is not linked on the page, maybe somewhere else I do not know, but the most important part of this class is the call to `$db->esc()` that escapes and probably sanitize user input. It is very important that you **never make any call to the database without sanitizing user input**, to avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/SQL_Injection).

Usually, the "esc" equivalent would use [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php). But do read the note, where they state that you should database specific escape functions depending on the database you're using (Like `mysqli_real_escape_string` for MySQL). Database abstraction class are really useful for that kind of stuff :).

Comment: Yes, the authors make comment on this below that code: "The Database database abstraction class is used to hide database implementation details for the purpose of this example, and should not be taken to represent any actual, existing library class."

Comment: OK :). I didn't read everything. However my point stand, the most important part of their code is sanitizing user input by calling `$db->esc`, probably using addslashes. See my edited post for it :)

Comment: Most good!  And in other manners, the Wikibooks page is good do you think?  I am using it, you see, for learning.

Comment: It is always a good thing to use experienced dev knowledge. These guys seems to know enough as to use database abstraction classes, so I'd say they what it needs to teach. Then, it depends on your background. But PHP is quite easy to learn, and you will also learn a lot by simply writing code and reading other codes. I learned PHP (and programation in general) mostly by myself, reading dociumentation and code :). To the conclusion: yes, I think the wikibook pages seems good enough for you to learn there, but you will have to improve by yourself after ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the wikibooks page is a reasonable, low-level (i.e. no libraries) description of a login system in PHP.  There's lots missing, but what's there is complete.  But then, I'm biased. ;-)